# Create nested pthread

Tags: c, pthreads

I didn't use C for long time and I don't remember if it is possible to create a thread from another thread.
If I try, I get this error:

```
sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
```

Aborted

Is there a workaround to lunch a thread from another one? Is there anything special I should set in attributes to make it work?

Thanks

PS: I should use only pthread and not fork() as required by an university project

Comment: it should be possible, but then where is your code...

Comment: I will simplify the stuff a little bit and if I can't solve the problem I'll post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error has nothing to do with threads. It's an indication that you've corrupted the memory used by malloc for bookkeeping purposes, probably by overflowing a buffer in a block you obtained from malloc.

Any thread can create new threads; there is no restriction on that.

Comment: Thank you.
Without the creation of the thread there's no error, that's why I'm a little bit lost in searching for the problem.
I will continue my search...thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: The internal malloc calls that happened to be made along with creating the thread probably just triggered the crash...

Comment: I found the problem and in fact it was related to a malloc. Thanks again for your help.